# JDBC Read without cursor

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8

I have to read huge data from the database (for example lets consider more than 500 000 records). Then I have to save the read data to a file. I have many issues with cursor (not only memory issue).

**Is it possible to do it without cursor, for example using stream? If so how can I achieve it?**

Comment: Which database system and driver are you using (I'm guessing MySQL, because it has the habit of always fetching all rows), and please show the code used. JDBC drivers can (and depending on exact use will) fetch rows in batches, meaning memory is not a problem, if used correctly.

Comment: @Thomas - Please [edit] your question to indicate the database platform you are using and include a [mcve] to show us an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced working with huge data (almost 500 milions of records). I simply used PreparedStatement query, ResultSet and of cource some buffer tweaking through:

```
setFetchSize(int)
```

In my case, i split the program into threads because the huge table was partitioned (each thread processed one partition) but i think that this is not your case.
It is pointless to fetch data through cursor. I would rather use the database view or SQL query. Do not use ORM for this purpose.

According to your comment, your best option is to limit JDBC to fetch only specific number of rows instead of fetching all of them (this helps to begin processing faster and does not load entire table into ResultSet). Save your data into collection and write it into file using BufferedWriter.  You can also benefit from multi-core CPU to make it run in more threads - like first fetched rows run in 1 thread, other fetched rows in second thread. In case of threading, use synchronized collections and be aware that you might face the problem of ordering.

Comment: could you show some code, how do you split code into threads? What do you mean "or proper SQL query."? Please expand your answer

Comment: @ThomasBanderas Please, describe your problem more precisely so i can answer your specific needs.

Comment: I want to make select * from table, do some mapping (for example, change some column names) and write it to file. Firstly I have memory issue when I want to fetch whole table by one query, now I use pagination but it is really slow. It's intresting how do you split program into threads

Comment: For future reference, 8 million records is nothing!

Comment: @JacobG. Please add some useful comments, not useless